# MySQL regex operator "maybe is there"

Tags: mysql, regex, perl

Sorry for stupid formula of question, but I don't know how to say it.

So in `perl` I have this regex:

```
/$string(\?.*?)?$/
```

For example I have this strings:

```
asdf
asdf?moo=foo
asdf?foo
asdfghjkl
blah
blahblah
```

And now I looking for `asdf`, `asdf?moo=foo` and `asdf?foo` strings.

How can I say this in MySQL `REGEXP`?

Comment: Can you please provide more details? Did you have a look at REGEXP function of mysql?

Comment: I know the REGEXP function, but I have problem with the expression. I update my question with examples.

Comment: Your `/$string(\?.*?)?$/` is exactly the same as `/$string(\?.*)?$/` and this is supported by MySQL. Just do not forget to use two backslashes before the literal `?`.

Comment: @stribizhev: Please send this message an answer to close this question. Thx.

Comment: @netdjw: Done, please check.

Comment: @netdjw this question is not "closed" until you mark an answer as accepted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your `/$string(\?.*?)?$/` is exactly the same as `/$string(\?.*)?$/` and this is supported by MySQL. It is true because lazy quantifier `*?` is matching any number of any characters but a newline up to the end of string, and thus it is equal to greedy quantifier `*`.

Greedy `*` is supported as per [MySQL REGEXP reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html). Other quantifiers that are supported:

- `?` - one or zero occurrences
- `+` - 1 or more occurrences
- `{n,m}` - *n* to *m* occurrences (limiting quantifier)

Just do not forget to use two backslashes before the literal `?`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a regex for this at all. The following is equivalent, and may perform better, as it does not require the MySQL query optimizer to recognize that the regular expression has a constant prefix:

```
column = 'asdf' OR column LIKE 'asdf?%'
```

(The `%` character in a LIKE pattern is equivalent to `.*` in a regular expression.)